Why would my washing machine drain pipe back up when someone else does laundry in an apartment?
I live on the ground floor of an apartment building with 6 floors. Every week when someone does laundry, the water and suds come pouring out of my washing machine drain pipe.
Plumbers snaked the drain pipe and didn’t find anything. They then busted through the wall and snaked the main water line where they did find and removed a clog. That didn’t work as it still floods my kitchen.
The kitchen sink gurgles really loud right before it happens.
Plumbers have now decided it’s someone using a lot of detergent.

It might be a vent problem.  The part of the main drain that goes though the roof.  Bird nests/stuff can stop air from getting in creating a vacuum.  Remember the old trick of filling a glass with water and placing a piece of paper over the top, and then turning it upside down.  Sink gurgles is a sign.  Too much detergent can also cause problems.

@crip659 please expound on the glass of water and piece of paper trick. I do not remember that one and am interested as to what it would indicate.

I would vote for an improper or clogged vent stack in the plumbing not allowing enough air into the system as the washing machines attempt to drain.

@ArchonOSX  Here is a link to the just the first of many search hits.  https://coolscienceexperimentshq.com/upside-down-glass-of-water-experiment/   Also called the magic water glass, if you want to do your own search.  Not exactly like a vent problem, but just something I remembered from my misspent youth.

As mentioned it could be inadequate or blocked vents. Or someone using too much detergent.
The next time it happens, go up the floors and politely ask if they are doing their laundry.
When you find the culprit, you have two choices.

Request them to use less detergent and explain why.
Request them to allow your plumber to check their plumbing at your expense. Again explain why.


Even though there are only six floors, this could be coming from dozens of apartments. Might not be possible.
